# setsockopt() SOL_IP API level and IPT_SO_SET_REPLACE switch

Tags: c, linux, sockets

What exactly does `SOL_IP` mean as the API level of the `setsockopt` function
and what exactly does the `IPT_SO_SET_REPLACE` switch do?

I tried to search for both in Google but I found nothing.
Please help me understand them (if you can expand and explain with examples I'd really appreciate it)

Answer (score 3):

`SOL_IP` is the network layer being addressed by the socket option. For example, an ordinary TCP socket encompasses the TCP layer, then the IP layer under it, and so forth. `setsockopt` is used to pass miscellaneous instructions down to a particular layer to request some service, feature or operation: basically anything that you might need to configure that doesn't directly match up with a system call. (The "API level" referred to in the man page is basically the same thing that I'm calling "layer" here.)

Some that you often see in linux programs (and examples of use) include:

- `SOL_PACKET` (configure packet ring, add/drop multicast group memberships)
- `SOL_IP` (set/configure various IP packet options, IP layer behaviors, [as here] netfilter module options)
- `SOL_TCP` (TCP_NODELAY, TCP-specific keepalive params)
- `SOL_SOCKET` (REUSEADDR, keepalives)

The layers you can address in a `setsockopt` depend on the kind of socket that you created. Here, it's the IP layer being addressed.

In this case, the option being passed down is `IPT_SO_SET_REPLACE` -- it's not a "core" IP option, but is provided by the IP Tables module, which (IIUC) links itself into the network stack via the "netfilters" interface. I'm not familiar with IP Tables details, but the option appears to be an instruction to IP Tables to replace a set of rule table entries. I think using it would require pretty intimate knowledge of IP Tables to use this socket option.

Comment: The exploit originated by Vitaly Nikolenko exploited this:

https://github.com/offensive-security/exploit-database-bin-sploits/raw/master/sploits/40053.zip

and this:

https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/40049/

And the vulnerability is CVE-2016-4997.     Good example if you want to know how to use IPT_SO_SET_REPLACE.

Answer (score 0):

Just to focus on IPT_SO_SET_REPLACE option.

It is to replace the iptable with a new chain rule (see -R option):

https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/iptables-tutorial.html

http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html

The above are the command line option to use.   If you want to see the C program, just "apt-get source iptables" to get the source code, and then view libiptc/libiptc.c to see how SO_SET_REPLACE is used:

```
ret = setsockopt(handle->sockfd, TC_IPPROTO, SO_SET_REPLACE, repl,
                 sizeof(*repl) + repl->size);
if (ret < 0)
        goto out_free_newcounters;
```

Which is essentially is to replace the new chain rule, by creating and compiling a new iptable.

More info:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables